# Is it possible to load a WebUserControl.ascx to a panel in default page like we have in Winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

I am having a default page namely default.aspx in this i will have panel. And i will have 2 other forms namely Webusercontrol1.ascx and Webusercontrol2.ascx i will design the page with some controls now is it possible to load this page in to the panel which was on default page like as we did in WINFORMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web user controls (.ascx) can definitely be loaded into a panel.

Web forms (.aspx) cannot.

Are you trying to *dynamically* load your user controls into a panel?  If so, you can do that too, but you have to do it on *every* postback.

To add a control to your panel from the code behind, simply create it, and then add it to the Controls collection of the panel.  Just remember, this has to be repeated on *every* subsequent postback.

```
WebUserControl uc = new WebUserControl();
panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Just be sure to register your user control in your aspx file

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="WebControl"  %>
```

Comment: Can i have a sample code how can i get that webusercontrol in to  a panel and can i load this on some other actions instead of pageload

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the one i required

```
UserControl usr1 = (UserControl)LoadControl("WebUserControl.ascx");
```

Comment: I think either will work, won't they?  +1 anyway, that's certainly cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

In ascx:

```
<%@ Register src="RC01.ascx" tagname="RC01" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"> </asp:Panel>
```

In ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RC01 uc1 = (RC01)LoadControl("RC01.ascx");
    Panel1.Controls.Add(uc1);
}
```

Comment: How is this helpful to the questioner?

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.